# Copying and pasting between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

So I currently have three workbooks, I have created a folder in my Desktop, and where I am using workbook x, through a range on a cell to open up workbook called `m` (old) and workbook called `n` (new).  I am then updating the old with the new.

Problem

Once I have opened up `m`, I am having to do a save as of the file as a newname. I am keen to know is there way of referring to it without using the workbook newname, as this workbook name would be concatenated  with today's date and the name can be quite long and time consuming to type. I have produced several subroutines, one to remove protection etc,. and one for carrying out the coping actions and I am calling the subroutines, I just want to now if there is way of linking the newsaved name to some of the subroutines from referencing. Alternatively the old file could be saved at the very end. I am keen to pursue this avenue as I will be playing in certain other cases with four workbooks.

I have taken this code and amended it, but I am unable to open both spreadsheets, the strange thing when i block out the code and go through a test both work for each path they work, but not at the same time.

this is the code i amended, which i was able to find in

```
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set x = Workbooks.Open("path to copying book")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("path to pasting book")

Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Sheet you want to copy from")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Sheet you want to copy to")

With ws1   
    .Cells.Copy ws2.cells
    y.Close True
    x.Close False
End With

End Sub
```

this is my code where it is not opening both workbooks

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws  as Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lst As Long,
Dim r1, r2 As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Sheets("x").Range("A4").Value")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Sheets("x").Range("A5").Value")
With wb2
Call Wbkunprtect()
```

I would be grateful for some help, please for those who are trigger happy can you hold back from pressing the down arrow some of us are not excel knowledgeable and also trying to learn and do not want to be banned from asking questions, I am trying to move data between two workbooks wb1 and wb2, through another wb i have completed my code, and this is the bit which stopping me from going forward.

I have learned a great deal from this site the reason I asked certain questions as I am reluctant to use select or activate as I have been told this is a bad habit you have to keep away from.

Comment: Once you saved it you can refer to it as "ActiveWorkbook", until you open or select another workbook.

Comment: I do not want to be using ActiveWorkbook or select or Activate, can you come out with other solutions please

Comment: Workbook variables?

Comment: I need an example. When I change my file to a newname, how can I link it all the variables, when I do this I keep getting errors

Comment: You need [google](https://www.google.hu/search?client=opera&q=vba+workbook+variable&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). And an occasional please would be nice. :)

Comment: Your help would be appreciated

Comment: `Dim MyBook as Workbook` `Set MyBook=ThisWorkbook` or `Set MyBook=ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: I am changing the name,  when I do a save as to a newname, can I use the Newname to refer to the other subroutines I will be calling which linked to the newname of the workbook will these be recognised

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you'll need to use a WorkBook object! the WorkBook object will have the instance of the newly added workbook. It is as simple as that:

```
Sub example_new_workbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs ("path where you want to save")
End Sub
```

That way, "wb" will have the instance of the new workbook, and you can use freely to reference that new workbook. Remember, the WorkBooks object holds all the instances of all open workbooks, so you can get the reference for any other workbook through this object.

As to make it "Global", you can declare it outside the "Sub" scope, so the variable will be permanent as long as the module (or wherever you put your code) is open like this:

```
public wb as Workbook

Sub <your_routines>()
...
End Sub
```